# Android Spinner: How to catch when user exits spinner leaving selected value as-is?

Tags: android, spinner

When a spinner comes up, it usually has a value preselected. If the users explicitly selects another item, my onClickItem handler is getting called.  But i did not find a way to detect when the user wants to keep the the currently selected list_item as is?  How is the user supposed to exit such a spinner when they like the current value?  Could you add a close button or something to just let them exit without having to reselect the already selected item to exit?  Also if they do reselect same item, how do you detect this?  I don't think my handlers are getting called for this.

To be clear I need to know two things:

1) when user want to keep current value how do they exit the spinner?  Is it by reselecting the already selected item. If this is the case, how do I detect this in code so I can close out the dialog?

2) are there any other options for letting user close out a spinner without having them reselect the already selected value? for example providing a dialog close button?  Would like to know how others are handling this.  Thanks

Comment: I posted an identical question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148288/is-there-a-workaround-to-the-onitemselectedlistener-bug If you get your answer, please link it to mine, or just come answer it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user can exit the spinner's dialog by pressing the hardware back key.  That's what the key is for - to back out of activities and dialogs.  If the currently selected item is selected, that also exits the spinner's dialog. There's generally no need for special handling to allow cancelling the selection, since the the user can directly exit the spinner dialog without making a selection.

Comment: the onNothingSelected event is NOT fired upon the depression of the back key. Also, the larger issue is when the user clicks an item that is already clicked. That also makes the spinner go away, but also doesn't produce any callback. So, no offense, but your answer neither addresses the problem nor solves even the problem you are choosing to address!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the onNothingSelected event, edited to remove.  Still, I think the questions that were summarized at the end of the original post were addressed.  How does the user exit a spinner, and does the user have other options besides selecting the currently selected item?

Comment: The user can close the spinner by touching outside its bounds. Best I can tell, no callback is fired.