# Is there a workaround to the OnItemSelectedListener bug?

Tags: android

I suspect the answer is no, but thought I'd ask...

I have a Spinner that needs to reveal a hidden "proceed" button when the user has made a selection.  However, since the OnItemSelectedListener is fired when the spinner is first rendered, and since it doesn't fire again when the user re-selects the item that is already highlighted, there doesn't appear to be a way to use this event to reveal a hidden button (or really do anything) contingent on the user having made a selection.

Is there some alternative way to do this?
AdapterView has a ClickListener which just throws an exception, so that's a non-starter. And it doesn't seem to have any other notification scheme for when the user first makes contact with it, or when it closes... unless I'm missing something? (wouldn't be the first time).

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a Spinner that needs to reveal a hidden "proceed" button when the user has made a selection.

The user has always made a selection. There is no concept of a `Spinner` without a selection. Hence, do not hide the "proceed" button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying exactly. There is a default selection (item 0) when the spinner first loads.  The user has not "made" that selection. It is made for them. I understand that as a developer it may be tempting to say "if they don't bother selecting, they've selected the default, BY default... but that is not my Client's requirement. They want to mandate that the user actually choose something.

Comment: @Dr. Dredel: My point is that `Spinner` does not support your client's model very well. There are three options. 1). Hack in an extra first item to your adapter that is the "no selection" item, and detect when the user switches off from it. 2). Your client adapts to the behavior of `Spinner` and stops expecting users to always make a positive selection. 3). You use something else for your UI (e.g., `singleChoice` `ListView`) which supports the notion of there being no selection. This last choice includes the possibility of you writing your own widget that behaves the way you want.

Comment: Yep... I think those are my options.  But this begs an interesting follow-up question. Is there any way to write a custom listener that listens for things that the Spinner doesn't natively broadcast? For example, the moment it pops open or the moment the user clicks on one of the radio buttons within?

Comment: @Dr. Dredel: "Is there any way to write a custom listener that listens for things that the Spinner doesn't natively broadcast?" -- probably not, short of cloning `Spinner` and probably `AbsSpinner` into your own project and making changes to the code. There's always the chance that you'll get lucky and the method that does the non-evented thing is in the SDK, so you can override it, chain to the superclass, and fire your event. However, that's far from certain.

Comment: @CommonsWar can we do something using custom key linster spiner.setOnKeyListener(l) ?

Comment: @dhams: I am sure that you can do *something* "using custom key linster", but nothing that would seem to be of relevance to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this isn't a solution, per se, but from the sound of things, it is a requirement that the user select SOMETHING to be allowed to continue, correct? What if you add, as the first item in the spinner, an unrelated item, saying something like "Please Select One..."? Have that as the default chosen item, then the user will have to make a different selection to continue, hence, the listener will be fired.

Just a thought. :)

Comment: that is in fact exactly what I had, until the client decreed that they don't like that being the first option, so, I'm at the drawing board again :)

Comment: Gah, too bad! :) I don't have another answer for you, unfortunately. :P

Answer (score 1):

I've seen in an [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065955/android-spinner-how-to-catch-when-user-exits-spinner-leaving-selected-value-as-i) answer here on stackoverflow that [onNothingSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) will enable you to detect this.

That answer was the only one and wasn't accepted, and I haven't tried it myself, but give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: man, that sounded SO good for a second... I thought OF COURSE!, how did I miss that?! But sadly, that (almost entirely useless callback) is there for when you programatically delete a selected member of the adapter array out from under the listener.  I suppose that's useful in some (highly unlikely) case, but what would be a lot MORE useful is the much more common issue of someone re-selecting a pre-selected item! I feel like I MUST be missing something! How can something so commonly needed be so glaringly missing?!