# Selecting the currently selected item in a spinner

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I have a spinner widget that only has one item by default, "Create new..."

My problem is if there is only one item in the spinner list, it's already selected, so clicking on it again doesn't trigger anything.

Is there any way to detect when an item is re-selected?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a workaround to the OnItemSelectedListener bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148288/is-there-a-workaround-to-the-onitemselectedlistener-bug)

Comment: The above link should help. :) Short answer: No. There are some workarounds though.

Comment: Hmmm.... looks like it's back to the drawing board...

Comment: duplicate of "How can I get an event in Android Spinner when the current selected item is selected again"

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele