# How to display text in a spinner that is different then the option selected?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hopefully my question is self explanatory; if not here is what I'm trying to do.
I have a spinner that has 5 options. If the user selected options 1-4 I want the text in the spinner to display "Level 1" instead of the actual value that was selected.

example~

red is selected -> spinner displays "Level one"

green is selected -> spinner displays "Level one"

blue is selected -> spinner displays "Level one"

yellow is selected -> spinner displays "Level one"

Level Not Reached is selected ->spinner displays "Level Not Reached"

Is this possible? If so how should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a new `class` with `color` and `level` as its properties.

After that, create a custom `adapter` for your `spinner` and call `getLevel` (the getter) to display the `level` but use `getColor` to get the value.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a good idea. However I found a solution that goes a different direction. I will post what I did as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post that helped a lot with this question: [How to hide one item in an Android Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863378/how-to-hide-one-item-in-an-android-spinner).

I decided that a decent way to do it was to hide the "Level one" in the list. That way a user could not select it but I could set it as the current selection when a user selected a color.

This may not be the most elegant solution but it did work for what I needed