# Is it possible to hide/destroy some items of a spinner programmatically ?

Tags: android, spinner

I have 14 items in my spinner. But i want to hide some items for different conditions.

For eg

I want to hide last 2 items for condition 1,last 4 for condition 2 and so on..

Is it possible to hide/destroy items of spinner like hiding whole spinner using setVisibility method?

Comment: you can remove item from list and set adapter to spinner.

Comment: Just remove items from the list you're using to represent the spinner.

Comment: The Spinner gets the items from the Adapter so you just tell the Adapter which items you want to hide or show.  Adjust the `get*()` methods accordingly.

Comment: can you tell me what get methods? @DeeV

Comment: `getItem()`, `getCount()`, `getItemId()`, `getItemViewType()`, `getView()`, etc.  You only return the items that are visible and the count should be only the visible items.

Comment: Still dint get how can i hide items .Can you provide me with code? @DeeV

Answer (score 1):

You can try this custom adapter to hide items from spinner based on position of item in spinner.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

     private int hidingItemIndex;

     public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, int hidingItemIndex) {
         super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
         this.hidingItemIndex = hidingItemIndex;
     }

     @Override
     public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         View v = null;
         if (position == hidingItemIndex) {
             TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
             tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             v = tv;
         } else {
             v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
         }
         return v;
     }
 }
```

check this link for reference [How to hide one item in an Android Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863378/how-to-hide-one-item-in-an-android-spinner)

the other way would be removing item from array list and set to spinner.