# Why is OnItemSelectedListener only called when an item changes, but not on every user selection?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm using spinner controls in an Android application, and I handle user selections via an `onItemSelectedListener()` method. This seems to work okay when a different selection from the current one is made. I would like, under certain conditions to reset all spinners to default values and ensure that `onItemSelectedListener()` is called for all.

Is it part of Android's semantics that `onItemSelectedListener()` is only called when user selection changes. Is there a way to force `onItemSelectedListener()` to be called?

Comment: Wait, you described the _opposite_ of how a Spinner works. Spinners throw a RuntimeException when you use an OnItemClickListener and the OnItemSelectedListener is called _regardless_ of whether the user re-selected the previous selection or made a new choice...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I misspelled. I am using onItemSelectedListemer(). I've now edited my message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Spinner doesn't trigger any event when you select the same item as your currently selected item. You will need to make a custom Spinner in order to do this. See [How can I get an event in Android Spinner when the current selected item is selected again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele)

Answer (score 12):

**If you want "onItemSelected" of Spinner  to be fired, even if the item in the spinner is selected /if item selected and it is clicked again .
Then use  this custom class which extends spinner ,this worked  for me**

Then edit your activity with spinners like this , I changed

```
  static Spinner spinner1;
```

to

```
  static NDSpinner spinner1;
```

and

```
   variables.spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

to

```
   variables.spinner1 = (NDSpinner ) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

Also I changed the xml layout where the spinner  is located

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/place" />
```

to

```
    <com.yourpackagename.NDSpinner 
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/place" />
```

Spinner extension class:

```
 package com.yourpackagename;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.util.AttributeSet;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import java.lang.reflect.Field;

     /** Spinner extension that calls onItemSelected even when the selection is the same as       its previous value. 
       *   ie This is extended "Customized class of Spinner" to  get the "onItemSelected"      event even if the item in the
     *  Spinner is already  selected by the user*/
    public class NDSpinner extends Spinner {

      public NDSpinner(Context context)
      { super(context); }

      public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
      { super(context, attrs); }

      public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
      { super(context, attrs, defStyle); }


      private void ignoreOldSelectionByReflection() {
            try {
                Class<?> c = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
                Field reqField = c.getDeclaredField("mOldSelectedPosition");
                reqField.setAccessible(true);
                reqField.setInt(this, -1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception Private", "ex", e);
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }

      @Override
      public void  setSelection(int position, boolean animate)
      {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
          // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
          getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());


        }
      }
      @Override
      public void setSelection(int position) {
          ignoreOldSelectionByReflection();
          super.setSelection(position);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the same adapter every time if you want to do it using default spinner :

@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int position, long lng) {

```
   spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```