# problems in android spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to display messages based on selection of value from spinner.
so i used folowing code.

```
sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        String ar[]={"hello","abc"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerEampleActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ar);
        sp.setAdapter(adapt);
        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            if(arg2==0)
            {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(SpinnerEampleActivity.this);
            alert.setMessage("hello");
            alert.show();
            }
            else
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(SpinnerEampleActivity.this);
                alert.setMessage("abc");
                alert.show();
            }

        }
```

but if i select the already selected value from spinner i am not getting any message.
could any help me to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As alternative case you can use single choice dialog and aggregate selected item, instead spinner

Comment: Try this link [Custom Spinner][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182284/why-is-onitemselectedlistener-only-called-when-an-item-changes-but-not-on-every/18693760#18693760

This worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you clicks again the currently selected item, then it can not fire any event. So you  can not catch `setOnItemSelectedListener` for spinner to respond.

You need to create your custom spinner adapter to handle the click for the already selected item.

Comment: i tried inflating a textview to spinner and added onclicklistener to it.i gives my requirement.but when the option is selected,the dropdown options were not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following to get custom spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, selects)
                    {
                       @Override
                       public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                       {
                        View v = convertView;
                         if (v == null) 
                           {
                             Context mContext = this.getContext();
                             LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                              v = vi.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
                           } 
                         final TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custopspin);
                         int pos=position;
                         if(pos==0)
                         {
                             tv.setText("hello");
//                           sy
                         }
                         else if(pos==1)
                         {
                             tv.setText("abc");
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             tv.setText("hi");
                         }
                         tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                         tv.setClickable(true);
                         tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                         {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) 
                        {
                            if(tv.getText().toString().equals("hello"))
                            {
                                                                    }
                            else if(tv.getText().toString().equals("hi"))
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                            }
                        }
                     });    
                     return v;  
                    }              
                 };     
        timeslot.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

as said in above comment after selecting the option were not hiding.

Answer (score 0):

```
   sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String ar[]={"hello","abc"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(SpinnerEampleActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,ar);
    sp.setAdapter(adapt);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int position, long arg3) 
    {
 AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(SpinnerEampleActivity.this);
        alert.setMessage(ar[position]);
        alert.show();

    }
       @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        }
    });
```

That's all.........