# How to set current spinner text without changing associated selection list items

Tags: android, spinner

I have a Spinner with some values

```
| Monday       | 
| Thuesday     |
| Wednesday    |
| Thursday     |
| Friday       |
| Saturday     |
| USER DEFINED |
```

When the user choose `USER DEFINED` he can input a custom value in a dialog, assuming that I get this value as `String userDef="Your choice"`.

I need to set this String as current item, without change the spinner selection list, that must appear the same described above, also when the user clicks again on the spinner, something like in Google Analytics Android App, see the image.

*unclicked spinner*
[image: Unclicked spinner Google Analytics]
*clicked spinner*
[image: clicked spinner Google Analytics]

How could I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The key detail for implementing this is that the [`SpinnerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) interface used used by the `Spinner` has two different but related methods:

- [`getView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) - creates the view displayed in the Spinner itself.
- [`getDropDownView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) - creates the view shown in the drop down popup.

Therefore, to have an item that is displayed differently in the popup vs in the spinner itself, you just need to **implement these two methods differently**. Depending on the specifics of your code the details may vary, but a simple example would be something like:

```
public class AdapterWithCustomItem extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private final static int POSITION_USER_DEFINED = 6;
    private final static String[] OPTIONS = new String[] {
        "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Custom..." };

    private String mCustomText = "";

    public AdapterWithCustomItem(Context context){
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, OPTIONS);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position == POSITION_USER_DEFINED) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            tv.setText(mCustomText);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void setCustomText(String customText) {
        // Call to set the text that must be shown in the spinner for the custom option.
        mCustomText = customText;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // No need for this override, actually. It's just to clarify the difference.
        return super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
}
```

Then, when the user enters the custom value, you just need to call the `setCustomText()` method on the adapter with the text you want to display.

```
mAdapter.setCustomText("This is displayed for the custom option");
```

which produces the following result:

[image]

Since you are only overriding the `getView()` method, the drop down still shows the same text as defined in the option itself.

Comment: Thank you this solution is great, there is only a small problem: if I click again on Custom after the first time, doesn't happen anything and I have to click to another element before click custom to show the dialog again. Have you any suggestion to fix for this issue?

Comment: @AndreaF Yes, `Spinner` behaves that way by default (it doesn't fire `onSelectionChanged()` when you reselect the same item). However, there are some tricks for getting around it, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele

Comment: I don't want to reselect days but reselect 'custom' option.
May I get that piece of code??? please... Its always loaded from first in my code.

Comment: If I pass `custom value` from another activity that time it should be show that value with custom selection.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to implement a custom array adapter. First create a class for each entry:

```
public class Choice {
    // Represents the underlying value
    public String value;

    // Represents the user-displayed value
    public String text;

    public Choice(String value, String text) {
        this.value = value;
        this.text = text;
    }

    // Only the text will be shown, not the underlying value
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Then declare your adapter of `Choice` objects: `ArrayAdapter<Choice>`. Only the defined text will be shown, and you can access the underlying value whenever an item is selected:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
    int position, long arg3) {
    Choice choice = adapter.get(position);
    // Set the value of the choice, not the text
    myValue = choice.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the USER DEFINED   string to the Array list  >

call notifyDatasetChanged() >

Get the size of new array list>

and then call

```
         spinner.setSelection(Index of USER DEFINED);
```

or

```
          spinner.setSelection(Arraylist.size()-1);
```

Comment: but this doesn't set the `String yourchoice` of my exasample to the spinner. I need to show a String that is different from the selection array and changes according the operations performed in the dialog that appears when the user click USER DEFINED.. Like in the Google Analytics Android App