# Spinner on item click functionality to be add

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner in my android app which is used to call an api to change the data in list view bellow it. I have used OnItemSelectedListener for this, but when I click the same item again, nothing happens, unless I change it to some other item and again click on the item I needed. I want to use something similar to OnItemClick, as OnItemClick is not supported by spinner. Suggest me an alternative, please.

Answer (score 0):

Took from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele) answer. Unfortunately, android Spinner doesn't provide functionality, that you want, but you can extend it and handle clicks manually:

```
public class NDSpinner extends Spinner {

    public NDSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NDSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void
    setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }


        @Override
        public void setSelection ( int position){

            boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
            super.setSelection(position);
            if (sameSelected) {
                // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
                getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
            }
        }

    }
}
```