# Trigger Spinner event when selection does not change

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-spinner

I have a Spinner dropdown with 3 items (they represent dates that can be selected).

- Now
- Weekend
- Custom Date

'Custom Date' is special, when I select it I display a DatePickerDialog.
The problem is that when 'Custom Date' is already selected I cannot display again the DatePickerDialog.

SetOnItemSelectedListener fires only when you change selection, I tried OnItemClickListener but I get the exception

```
setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

Any way to detect the click/select event even when you don't change selection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some below you are excepting?

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewbyId(R.id.spinner);
int position = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition(); 
String Text = yourCityList[position].toString();

String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: Yes, but I want that code to be called every time when I select some (even the same) item.

Comment: Then you need write custom listener!

Comment: Could you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335306/how-can-i-get-an-event-in-android-spinner-when-the-current-selected-item-is-sele